# Prevent postback from Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, webforms

I've got a `runat="server"` anchor that has `__doPostBack` in the `href`.

I'd like to validate that another field has been completed when the anchor is clicked, and only allow the postback to occur if the field is not empty.

I've added a custom directive to handle this, which is as follows:

```
angular.module('app').directive('notEmpty', function ($timeout, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (event) {

                return $timeout(function () {
                    var elementToCheckNotEmpty = $document[0].querySelector(attrs.notEmpty);

                    if (!elementToCheckNotEmpty.value) {
                        scope.addInvalidClass = true; // input has an ng-class binding to $scope.addInvalidClass
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is not preventing the postback. Updating the `scope` property and adding the class to the input is working, because I see the invalid class applied for a couple of seconds while the postback is occurring.

I understand that `$timeout` returns a promise, so I have tried chaining a then on to the `$timeout` like so:

```
return $timeout(function () {
    var elementToCheckNotEmpty = $document[0].querySelector(attrs.omwNotEmpty);

    if (!elementToCheckNotEmpty.value) {
        scope.addInvalidClass = true;
    }
}).then(function () {
    if (scope.addInvalidClass) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

But this is not preventing the postback either. It's a webforms project with a shared masterpage so I can't really update the `form` element without potentially affecting a lot of other pages. The form does have an empty `action` attribute. Also, the `ng-controller` attribute is on an element *inside* the `form` element, not sure if that makes a difference...

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to Angular btw so apologies if this is trivial!

Comment: Why do you need use $timeout?

Comment: Without it, the ng-class binding I have on the element I want to be not empty doesn't appear to work. The property I am changing on the scope *is* being changed, but the binding doesn't add the class. But, it **does** prevent the postback

Comment: The binding does not change as click is not within angular digest cycle. Instead of $timeout enclose the scope changes with scope.$apply() or you could just use ng-click instead of element.bind.

Comment: Yep, that's got it :) Thanks. If you have time to add it as an answer, I will mark as accepted and up-vote it. Thanks again, much appreciated

Comment: You are welcome and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $timeout adds the function to async queue thereby not preventing the postback. And the binding does not change  when not using $timeout service as click is not within angular digest cycle. Instead of $timeout enclose the scope changes with scope.$apply() or you could just use ng-click instead of element.bind.